# Use of manual pagination "$perPage" parameter

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, pagination

So I've been working on a pagination system that pulls data externally, after finally figuring out through trial and error I got the solution that works. While going through it something struck me as odd, as per the documentation `$paginator = Paginator::make($items, $totalItems, $perPage);`

I was wondering what's the actual use of the `$perPage` parameter? You would think that what ever number is specified would show that many items. But with manual pagination you have to limit the results that are passed into `$items` in order for it to work, otherwise you get the output of all items *(as shown in code block below)*. Is manual pagination flawed? because if `$perPage` doesn't match the total number of items in the array `$items` it shows everything.

Example: `Paginator::make( array('10xarray') ), 10, 2);` it would show 5 pages with 2 items per page? where in reality it actually shows 10 items with 5 pages that all show the same 10 items.

```
<?php
class MainController extends BaseController {

    public function library()
    {
        $this->layout->title = 'testing';
        $this->layout->main = View::make('library/layout');
        // Pagination data
        $media = array(
            array('title' => 'test'),
            array('title' => 'test'),
            array('title' => 'test'),
            array('title' => 'test')
        );
        $perPage = 2;
        $currentPage = Input::get('page', 1);
        $pagedData = array_slice($media, ($currentPage - 1) * $perPage, $perPage);

        $this->layout->main->paginated = Paginator::make($pagedData, count($media), $perPage);

        if(Request::ajax()) {
            return Response::json(
                View::make(
                    'library/layout', 
                    array('paginated' => $this->layout->main->paginated)
                )->render()
            );
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it isn't flawed. it is intended behavior.

this manual `paginator` is just a container. nothing more, nothing less. how you implement it, is upon you.

without a `LIMIT` query, you can never do a pagination. when you use `pagination()`, laravel does the work under the hood. when you go for manual, you have to do it manually and get greater control.

why do you think it is called *manual pagination* in the first place?

Comment: As per the question title, `$perPage` has no effect on the pagination other than simply showing page numbers. The only time it works as it should is when it's the exact same number as `$items`, which begs the question: Why is it there? when it's just a `count($items)`

Comment: because laravel calculates the number of page by dividing the total number of datas by this `$perPage` (also equal to `$item` you are refering). They __Must__ be same. The main responsibility of pagination is to build links for pages, __NOT__ fetching datas from the database. the 2nd part, is a responsibility of the programer.

Comment: I already understand all that, including the use cases of the pagination, the point I'm trying to figure out is can `$perPages` be dropped all together. If every time it **must** be equal to the count of `$items` then it's not necessary and since if you put in any other number it breaks it... unless there is another use case for it which hasn't been mentioned.

Comment: `$perPage` can not be dropped due to reason i wrote earlier. again it is just a container. You have to do everything manually. `$perPage` and `$item` __MUST BE EQUAL__. No other way. the whole pagination relies on this behavior.